# Server running on guest virtualbox is not visible from host?

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, virtualization, virtualbox, django

I'm using virtualbox to run an Ubuntu server from os x. I have NAT and bridged connections set up and I am able to ping back and forth, ssh into the guest box, transfer files with scp, etc. However, when I start the Django development server I'm unable to view this from the host.

```
$ - manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

When viewing 192.168.56.1:8000 the page is unable to load.

Here is the ip details for the guest machine, obtained from host:

```
vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
inet 192.168.56.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

Within the Ubuntu server I get the following, the first is for the NAT adapter the second is the bridged connection:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:1f:cd:51  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe1f:cd51/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1955 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1080 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:173919 (173.9 KB)  TX bytes:159672 (159.6 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:cf:e8:7f  
          inet addr:192.168.56.1  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fecf:e87f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22205 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1867168 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)
```

**EDIT**: If I browse to `http://192.168.56.1` without the port set, it shows my hosts localhost. So presumably the problem is to do with the host not being able to distinguish between itself and the guest?

Comment: Can you connect to django from the server ?

Comment: Yes, if I `curl http://0.0.0.0:8000` I get the standard welcome screen.

Comment: @rlayte: What about to 192.168.56.1 ?

Comment: Yep, same output.

Comment: Is Django on the ubuntu server ? What happens when you browse to the ip address of the ubuntu server:8000 ?

Comment: 192.168.56.1 should be the address of the Ubuntu server so that's what I would have  expected to work.

Comment: @rlayte: You can check by running the command `ifconfig` on your Ubuntu system and looking at what `inet addr:` is assigned to your ubuntu server.

Comment: Yes, exactly. As I said, 192.168.56.1 is the guest's ip and is what I expected to work initially. Posted ip details in post.

Answer (score 1):

I have CentOS guess on MacOS hos and on my machine
192.168.56.1 IS the host, my guest is 192.168.56.101.  So seems to me you WERE talking to the host not guest.

If you try to connect to the guest at 192.168.56.101 and fail - is the guest's firewall in the way?   (`/bin/service iptables stop` I think)